# Equity cannot be redeemed at the option of the holder

Tags: stocks, financial-literacy, equity

I was going through [Tier 1 Capital](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/t/tier1capital.asp) on Investopedia. I came across this note a couple of times in the article.

**Equity capital is inclusive of instruments that cannot be redeemed at the option of the holder.**

Can somebody explain this to me?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Accouting questions are off-topic unless they're related to financial statement analysis. I'll vote to reopen if you can add the purpose of your question to make it on-topic.

Comment: I don't think this is an accounting question at all, just financial literacy. Voting to reopen.

Comment: How is this an accounting question? Please reopen the question.

Comment: The concept in question can relate to preferred share investing in financial institution preferred shares, which are often held by retail investors for income. I vote to reopen.

Comment: I vote to reopen, and I might be able to answer the question. But could you give a little more context? This is about banking liquidity and the laws on how much they can lend out Vs hold.

Comment: @Chris Evans can you just explain me what it means the context of the linked article?

Comment: Why do you want to know what Tier 1 Capital is?

Comment: I was reading about the different reports that banks generate, out of curiosity. I came across Tier 1 Leverage Ratio and from there I jumped to Tier 1 Capital.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit complex, but remember that there can be different forms of equity, namely common and preferred. Common equity generally takes the form of exchange-listed common stock, but preferred equity can be a bit more complex, especially if its unlisted. Sometimes preferred equity instruments are issued with a tenor ("x" years) or as a perpetuity (i.e., never redeemed), and generally in the case of the former, there could be a feature that would let the holder redeem it early. Sometimes, a bank can also issue convertible debt that, upon the occurrence of certain trigger events (sometimes automatic, sometimes at either the holder's or the issuer's option), will convert into a specified type of shares (i.e., equity), which may or may not be redeemable).

Tl;dr, what Tier 1 capital seeks to capture is junior (i.e., loss absorbing) capital that isn't subject to being repaid (i.e., redeemed) outside of the bank's control and therefore a potential drain on its resources in the event of a downside scenario.